# Using Dynamically built query in SQL View

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have this view:

```
SELECT        CAST([IDNumber] AS varchar) AS IDNumber
FROM            [ViewXTimeData1]
UNION
SELECT        CAST([IDNumber] AS varchar) AS IDNumber
FROM            [ViewXTimeData2]
UNION 
SELECT       CAST([IDNumber] AS varchar) AS IDNumber
FROM            [ViewXTimeData3]
UNION
SELECT        CAST(vVisitorID AS varchar) AS IDNumber
FROM            [dbo].[tblVisitor]
```

The purpose of this view is to pull data from the 3 linked databases and the local database. I have a view of each that I then call in the main view (ViewXTimeDataAll).

Now what happened was that ViewXTimeData2's database went offline, due to connectivity issues, this crashed the view and the application could not get any info from ViewXTimeDataAll.

So what I did was I created this:

```
DECLARE @GETVIEWS NVARCHAR(2000);

    SET @GETVIEWS = ''

IF Exists(select top(1) * from SZAAGATAA01.Xtime900.dbo.LSCTagLookup)
    SET @GETVIEWS = @GETVIEWS + 'SELECT CAST([IDNumber] AS varchar) AS IDNumber FROM [ViewXTimeDataAGA] UNION '

IF Exists(select top(1) * from SZADELTAA01.Xtime900.dbo.LSCTagLookup)
    SET @GETVIEWS = @GETVIEWS + 'SELECT CAST([IDNumber] AS varchar) AS IDNumber FROM [ViewXTimeDataCHO] UNION '

IF Exists(select top(1) * from SZADELTAA01.Xtime900.dbo.LSCTagLookup)
    SET @GETVIEWS = @GETVIEWS + 'SELECT CAST([IDNumber] AS varchar) AS IDNumber FROM [ViewXTimeDataDEL] UNION '

    SET @GETVIEWS = @GETVIEWS + 'SELECT CAST(vVisitorID AS varchar) AS IDNumber FROM [dbo].[tblVisitor]'

    EXEC(@GETVIEWS);
```

Works great. If the database is offline it omits it and still gets the information from the available databases, which is exactly what I need... BUT can't use variables in a View (I find out after writing this...).

Should add that I need to filter the data, hence the reason I put everything in a view.

Comment: No you can't use dynamic SQL in a view and also if the linked server is unavailable doing an `exists` from it will still throw an error rather than false anyway

Comment: High performance and high availability just don't go with "linked server". You can't use a view, so that is a dead-end. Perhaps a stored procedure can be used but your code is based on luck - you're just ignoring the errors that occur.

Comment: look at table valued functions

Comment: @RegBes - I don't see how they would help. You can't use dynamic SQL in those either.

Comment: And you've learned some bad habits along the way. You should always define the length of any variable-length datatypes. Perhaps you don't really (nor should you) cast the ID columns to varchar? And think carefully about using UNION ALL vs. UNION - duplicate removal can be a slow, expensive operation.

Comment: @SMor This is a fairly limited application, only a couple of people use it. Fewer even use the section where this view is called, so High Performance is not a requirement.

Comment: @SMor Edit timer got me...

As for your second question, yes, we have xpats that have ID Numbers that is alphanumeric so I have to use varchar. I just shortened it for the above, I request a lot of other fields as well.

I am not a DBA , I do some programming on the side for tools here at work. So I probably do have a few bad habits :) I will define the length of the datatypes.

As a test I ran it with Union all : Union = 735 | Union All = 737

Comment: @MartinSmith Ahh I see what you mean... the server was back up when I tested the query... back to the drawing board...